# Is it possible to run linux on hand-held tablets?

Tags: python, android, django

I want to run a django app on a hand-held device. It'll need to run Python (obviously) and will write its data to an SQLite database.

Are there any tablets available that will let me do this? Specifically, if I bought an Android tablet, would I have to/be able to install linux instead, or would I be able to run it under Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Linux probably [Meego](http://meego.com/) is the best choice. There is no hardware for it yet, I believe, but there is [hardware for the predecessor Maemo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maemo#Hardware).

Running Django on Android is not possible, AFAIK. If you have a network connection the Django server yould be anywhere and you would just need a smartphone/tablet with a browser. That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you know if it's possible to take an Android tablet, reformat it and install Linux?

Comment: It is possible for some phones (see http://www.engadget.com/2010/07/08/ubuntu-joins-android-on-nexus-one-apocalyptic-repercussions-now/ ), but you'll have to check for each device if it is possible.

Comment: The Nokia N900 has Linux (Maemo, based on Debian) with Python installed by default. I have one of them, very cool device for programmers and other technical-types.

Comment: @MadScientist If you get interested in, running Django on Android is possible: http://keniallee.blogspot.com/2012/08/django-14-for-android-only-dev-runserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to run on a tablet or a hand-held device? Are netbooks okay?

There are plenty netbooks that run Ubuntu, on which you should be able to run python. I also remember that the sharp zaurus handheld devices were able to run Zope for example (be it very, very slowly)

In general, smaller, embedded systems (i.e. pandora) run versions of OpenWRT that use ipkg, and I think there are django packages for OpenWRT, so that may be an option as well.